# "Invalid blocks" when updating ephemeral message via response_url webhook

Tags: slack, slack-api

According to [Slack's documentation](https://api.slack.com/interactivity/handling#updating_message_response), you can use blocks to update an entire ephemeral message by simply replacing the entire message by setting `replace_original` as true when posting to the `response_url` provided in the interaction payload when using buttons.

However, when I'm sending the POST request to the provided `response_url` after a button has been pressed and I attempt to use blocks, I get the following error: `404 : [{"ok":false,"error":"invalid_blocks"}]`

Strangely enough, the payload I'm including for blocks is generated by the same method that creates the original ephemeral message which works fine without any issues.

I was able to replace the entire message with just a plain text message by using the `text` field indicated in the documentation and it works fine if I don't include the blocks array. I did find some documentation here for posting messages via incoming webhooks [here](https://api.slack.com/messaging/webhooks#advanced_message_formatting) but it looks the same as what I'm sending now.

Here's the body of the request I'm sending:

```
{
"blocks":
[
    {
        "type": "image",
        "imageUrl": "https://example.com/image.jpeg",
        "altText": "alt-text",
        "title":
        {
            "type": "plain_text",
            "text": "some text"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "actions",
        "elements":
        [
            {
                "type": "button",
                "text":
                {
                    "type": "plain_text",
                    "text": "Send",
                    "emoji": false
                },
                "value": "send",
                "style": "primary"
            },
            {
                "type": "button",
                "text":
                {
                    "type": "plain_text",
                    "text": "Find new",
                    "emoji": false
                },
                "value": "some text"
            },
            {
                "type": "button",
                "text":
                {
                    "type": "plain_text",
                    "text": "Cancel",
                    "emoji": false
                },
                "value": "cancel"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"replace_original": "true",
"text": "some fallback text"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two typos in your blocks: `imageUrl` and `altText`. Slack expects these to be snake case, i.e. `image_url` and `alt_text`.

You can use Slack's [Block Kit Builder](https://app.slack.com/block-kit-builder) to debug the blocks payload.

Comment: Damn, thanks. I was using the Java Slack API to post the first message but in the manual POST request Jackson was serializing it to camelcase by default... All works after a naming strategy change!